# Is there a function to divide values from one column to each (!) value from another? In R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) that looks like this:

```
   Code  Status Value
1     1 Treated   1.5
2     1 Treated   1.7
3     1 Treated   1.9
4     1 Control   2.1
5     1 Control   2.3
6     1 Control   2.5
7     2 Treated   1.6
8     2 Treated   1.8
9     2 Treated   2.0
10    2 Control   2.4
11    2 Control   2.6
12    2 Control   2.8
```

Here is its code:

```
df <- data.frame(Code = rep(c(1:2), each = 6),
           Status = rep(rep(c("Treated", "Control"), each = 3), 2),
           Value = c(1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8))
```

I need to divide each "Treated" value for each "Control" value within one "Code" (1, 2, etc).
Basically, I need it to work more or less like this:

```
# 1st "Value" in "Code" 1
df$Value[1]/df$Value[4]
df$Value[1]/df$Value[5]
df$Value[1]/df$Value[6]
# 2nd "Value" in "Code" 1
df$Value[2]/df$Value[4]
df$Value[2]/df$Value[5]
df$Value[2]/df$Value[6]
```

And so on... In order to do this I've created a for loop, that looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:2){
  for(j in 1:3){
 x <- df$Value[df$Code == i & df$Status == "Treated"]
 y <- df$Value[df$Code == i & df$Status == "Control"]
 vector <- x/y[j]
 print(vector)
  }
}
```

Results look like this.

```
[1] 0.7142857 0.8095238 0.9047619
[1] 0.6521739 0.7391304 0.8260870
[1] 0.60      0.68      0.76
[1] 0.6666667 0.7500000 0.8333333
[1] 0.6153846 0.6923077 0.7692308
[1] 0.5714286 0.6428571 0.7142857
```

And my problem is that I require further calculations with those results.
But, when I'm trying to extract the vector, so I can work with it, it contains only the last calculation:

```
[1] 0.5714286 0.6428571 0.7142857
```

Is there a better way to make the calculation?

P.s. For context: later I need to calculate MFV (membership function value) for each "Code", but I need to use min/max from all of the calculated (divided) values within "Value".

Answer (score 0):

Let's breakdown the problem. Suppose there's only one Code. The problem can be solved by:

```r
df %>%
  filter(Code == 1) %>%  # --> just select one Code for now
  group_by(Status) %>%   # --> For each status
  mutate(Trial = seq_along(Value)) %>% # --> add helper ID to each row
  spread(Status, Value) %>%       # --> convert rows into columns
  expand(Control, Treated) %>%    # --> create all possible combinations
  mutate(ratio = Treated/Control) # --> compute the ratio
```

Once we have this, we just need to be able to process for each Code. We can do it with a simple loop, here I am using `lapply` but `map` from `purrr` or a `for` loop would do the same.

```r
process <- function(df){
  df %>%
    group_by(Status) %>%
    mutate(Trial = seq_along(Value)) %>%
    spread(Status, Value) %>%
    expand(Control, Treated) %>%
    mutate(ratio = Treated/Control)
}

df %>% 
  nest(-Code) %>% 
  mutate(data = lapply(data, process)) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach. You can `group_by` each `Code` and `nest` the data.

Then, for each `Code`, you can use `outer` to give the product of your two vectors (treated and control) - however, you can provide the function `/` to give a ratio (divide).

After `unnest` you will have a column called `Ratio` that will contain a numeric matrix. Note that you will still have the `Code` column in your results which will be needed for future calculations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(Ratio = map(data, ~outer(.x$Value[.x$Status == "Treated"], .x$Value[.x$Status == "Control"], `/`))) %>%
  unnest(Ratio)
```

**Output**

```
   Code data             Ratio[,1]  [,2]  [,3]
  <int> <list>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [6 × 2]>     0.714 0.652 0.6  
2     1 <tibble [6 × 2]>     0.810 0.739 0.68 
3     1 <tibble [6 × 2]>     0.905 0.826 0.76 
4     2 <tibble [6 × 2]>     0.667 0.615 0.571
5     2 <tibble [6 × 2]>     0.75  0.692 0.643
6     2 <tibble [6 × 2]>     0.833 0.769 0.714
```